# Click a NSPushButton programmatically with "animation"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, nsbutton

I just ran into a problem I already know from other programming languages/frameworks ....
Whenever the user clicks a certain button on the keyboard, he triggers the same action than when a certain button in the GUI is pressed. ( Some guys call these "shortcuts" ;D )

To give the user an optical feedback, I would like to sorta "click" the button programmatically rather than calling the same functions that get called when the button is clicked.

If I set the button as a key equivalent in IB, it looks exactly as I want to have it.
Can't do that here as the shortcut should just be enabled if the right textfields have focus.

Couldn't find a method in NSButton or similar that sounded right.
I'm sure you guys can give me some direction!

Best and thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just send `performClick:` to the button.  It will highlight itself, send its action to its target, and then unhighlight itself.

```
[self.someButton performClick:self];
```

If you really want to just highlight and unhighlight the button manually, you can use the `highlight:` method.

```
[self.someButton highlight:YES]; // button appears pressed
[self.someButton highlight:NO]; // button appears unpressed
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for your answer .... why didn't I see that myself ... may be the time of day ;-)

Comment: I edited my answer.  You may have seen my original answer.  The new answer is better.

Comment: Yap, saw it. Edited mine, too ;D